# Mouse 4 and 5 for Mission Control pages?

Tags: macos, mac, mouse, mission-control

I am not a mac noob, and I have searched through system preferences, and yet I cannot find a way to use the scroll wheel left and right buttons to switch between Mission Control pages on my mac. I know the buttons are mouse 4 and 5 because in the Mission Control preference pane, I can set one of them to show my desktop (and it worked). In the preference pane, I was able to set mouse 3 to enter Mission Control, but it seems that the only places I can set a shortcut for Mission Control pages are in keyboard (which doesn't work with mouse buttons) and trackpad preferences which is no help either. Any ideas? (I am not afraid of terminal.)

Comment: Have a look at [SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/)

Comment: I am sure that would work, but it is a 30 day trial.